# The Laplace transform of the Heaviside function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, laplace-transform, contour-integration

I am studying complex analysis but, because I'm an engineer, I have a lot of doubts.
I'm going to present my doubts and it would be nice if someone helps me to see things clearly.

Let's start with the laplace transform of the heaviside function;

$$\int_0 ^\infty e^{-st} \ dt  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

The way we did this in class was straightforwad: $\int_0 ^\infty e^{-st} \ dt = \frac{e^{-st}}{-s} \big|_0^\infty = \frac 1s$

I believe that it's not rigorous; what theorem did we just apply?
It is not the fundamental theorem of calculus, because it deals with real functions.

It could be the fundamental theorem of calculus, complex version, that says that 
If $f$ is holomorphic in $U$ , then exists $F: F' = f$ and for every curve $\gamma: [a, b] \to \mathbb C$ we have $$\int_\gamma f(z) \ dz = F(\gamma(b)) - F(\gamma(a))$$

But our integrand in $(1)$ is a complex function of a real variable; it is not holomorphic, is it? I don't really know how to classify this type of functions.

So the only explanation is how we define complex integrals, that is $$\int f(t) = \int \text{Re } f(t) + i\int \text{Im } f(t)$$

Doing so, I have (setting $s = x + iy$)

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-st} \ dt = \int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\cos (yt) \ dt - i \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} \sin (yt) \ dt$$

They clearly converge ($x > 0$) but then I need to calculate them (how?) and show that their sum is indeed equal to $\displaystyle \frac 1{x +iy} = \frac 1s$

Can somebody answer a bit all the questions I have? I am a bit confused and it would really help me out a lot.

Comment: Do you know when Laplace transform exist?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yes.. That's why I can say $ x > 0$. Why do you ask? Have I overlooked something trivial?

Comment: No. Just I wanted to drive your attention to it! Only the parameter $s$ is complex! The integral is not a complex integral it is an improper integral!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal yes I know.. That's the whole point of the question :-)

Comment: Do you know how to handle an improper integral?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal technically that is not an improper integral because it is the lebsegue integral, not the riemann one. And I do, but how does it relate to the question? I am asking which theorems one can apply in this case :-)

Comment: Have not you known his background to decide what to tell him and not what to tell him?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20718/discussion-between-ant-and-mhenni-benghorbal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the matter explained by @PedroTamaroff in chat.

Basically $f(t)$ is a complex-valued function of a real variable, so I consider $f(z) = e^{-sz}$ which is its analytic continuation over $\mathbb C$ and consider the integral over the curve $[0, \infty]$; since $f(z)$ is holomorphic I can use the fundamental theorem of calculus and of course the resulting integral is the same I was set to evaluate.

(I hope I have understood it correctly)

Thanks again pedro!